# CartoDB polygon data for postal codes in Spain

Tags: carto, postal-code, spain

I have been testing CartoDB for a little while and I can't get maps by postal codes in Spain. The system says "no polygon data available for your selection".

But then I see some maps for Spain including postal code polygons. For example https://dgonzaco.cartodb.com/tables/sppodemos/public/table

Entering the table I see getJSON data containing the polygon data. Is this getJSON data generated by CartoDB, or is it needed to add it manually?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Those users are obtaining the data from their end, not geocoding it in CartoDB :)

In Spain, the postal code regions dataset is property of Correos, so it cannot be used as a source of the CartoDB Geocoder which is built by open data which allows commercial use according to their license.

You can try to obtain the postal code regions data by yourself and then run a SQL query in order to merge it with your actual data about the regions.

Comment: Thanks for the reply!  so.. providing that polygon data for spain postal codes gets aboyt 75MB, i can't use a free acount :(